# Socket is not listening using nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

Thanks for help in advance. I am getting following state from my console [See Server running console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yUHP.png). Below Snippet is my app.js code where express and node server running. If you see my socket code my console.log underneath socket connection is not showing in server logs. Socket is not listening my messages.

I have also upload my sample of code at github, here you can find that (github.com/ferozpuri/node-app) client socket code is in SocketController.js an Angular controller file.

Here is my app.js file code, As you can see console log for "Connection was made" never show. and same with socket console.

```js
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var engines = require('consolidate');
var routes = require('./routes');
var users = require('./routes/user');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

// view engine setup
//app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
//app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.engine('html', engines.nunjucks);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', users.list);

/// catch 404 and forwarding to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('A connection was made!');
    socket.on('chat.message', function (message) {
        console.log('New Message : ' + message);
    });
});



module.exports = app;
```

I am not getting socket response from node server. PLease let me know if i not explain this properly or any thing is not here.

**Server listing on port you can see this in screenshort or my project structure**

[Project structure & app listening port OR NPM START CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N46a7.png)

Comment: Do you call `app.listen(port)` or `server.listen(port)` somewhere ? Your server is not listening to anything, so you can't access it.

Comment: I have also upload my sample of code at github, here you can find my code: github.com/ferozpuri/node-app Just couple of files to create my scenario

Comment: You need the `server` (from the `http` module) to listen, not express (`app`) directly. (c.f. https://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4)

Answer (score 0):

You have set up all handlers but you did not initialize app.

```
http.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('App is listening on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jan, This is not working for me, express server already running on port 3000. After adding this line of code i am getting error "TypeError: http.listen is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

You did not start your server.  In your code, your server is created with this line:

```
var server = require('http').Server(app);
```

So, sometime after that, you need to add:

```
server.listen(80);    // or use whatever port number you want the server on
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, But still socket is not binding my event, I still unable to see my logs in this  url: https://www.dropbox.com/s/athkd5bve6yc9f4/socket%20issue.png?dl=0

Comment: @ferozpuri - Please show your client-side code.  Also, what version of socket.io are you running? And, why are there POST requests for your socket.io URL.  Something is wrong there.

Comment: Here is link of my my code sample. You can find client side code in "SocketController.js" file

small code not take your much time
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tnyvpec1yzeje82/chat-app.zip?dl=0

Comment: @ferozpuri - Sorry, but I'm not going to download a zip file and then decompress it on my hard drive (security reasons).  If you want us to look at your code, add it to your question or put it someplace where we can view it on the web such as jsFiddle.net or jsbin.com.

Comment: @jfriends - Thanks for your help.  I have upload my code to git

https://github.com/ferozpuri/node-app

Here is code url for socket client:
https://github.com/ferozpuri/node-app/blob/master/public/javascripts/socketController.js

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by adding following line of code  under constructing my express/after `var app = express();`

`var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(3000);`

@jfriend00 and @Sablor, Thanks both of you for show me right direction. my server already running on port "3000" so with port 80 its was not working. because it is conflicting with my XAMPP server. Thanks you guys for participating